# jscrollpane : change ArrowSizes

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I saw that it is possible to change the size or the arrows with "arrowSize: 30" here: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/examples.html (old version of jscrollpane)

But how can I change the sizes of the arrows in the new version?
I need the new version because it supports different placement of the arrows:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/arrow_positions.html

I don't see any option to change the size of the arrows, even when I use "arrowSize" like in the old version, nothing changes..

Thanks in advance!

Clemens

Comment: One secound after posting I found the solution:

.jspVerticalBar .jspArrow
{
 height: 33px; /* HEIGHT OF ARROWS */
}

Comment: You can post your own solution at the bottom of the page. And then accept that answer.